# nhibernate queryover.where Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I can not convert my SQL-code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Message
WHERE MessageId = @MessageId OR @MessageId IS NULL
```

To LINQ:

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Message> 
  .Where(p => p.MessageId == finder.MessageId || finder.MessageId == null)
  .List<Message>();
```

If `finder.MessageId` is not null - it's work. But I'm getting exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." if my variable `finder.MessageId` is null.

How can fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is finder null aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do, is to check the passed parameter during the "query building"

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Message>();

if(finder.MessageId != null) // only in this case we will append the filter
{
     query.Where(p => p.MessageId == finder.MessageId)
}

var list = query.List<StreetLight>();
```

The information is available on the App server, before we have to go to SQL, so we do not have to pass the OR expression to DB engine